# Simple jQuery animate question

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm must be doing something stupid, because I can't make this simple animate work :P

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: '#ff3300'
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: '#000000'
        }, 500);        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GY3UG/1/

It doesn't do the animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to reference jQuery UI script file too.  (In jsFiddle check the `jQuery UI 1.8.7` box). That's where the `animate` function is.

*( http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.js )*

Answer (score 0):

I would choose [jQuery Color](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt) personally as it's 4kb.